# Are "Cross Application Queries" possible using the Azure API format for app insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to make a query to Application Insights using the [Azure API format](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview/URL-formats) to retrieve data on multiple applications. I can successfully make queries for **any application without a join**.

I have previously done this using the Public API format, following the [documentation](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Cross-Resource-Queries) for making "cross-application queries" successfully. Under the Azure API schema, however, once I add a second application to a query - either using the implicit or explicit mechanisms described in the [documentation](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Cross-Resource-Queries) - I get an error of type `InsufficientAccessError` with the message: "The provided credentials have insufficient access to perform the requested operation".

If there are sufficient permissions to access either table individually, I would expect there to be sufficient to do a join. Is there a separate permission required to make these queries, or is it an issue with the API itself?

---

For reference, the Azure AD application has delegated permissions for:

- user_impersonation
- Directory.Read.All
- Group.Read.All
- User.Read
- User.ReadBasic.All
- User.ReadWrite

The user which is making the requests has the Owner role on all relevant applications.

And the final request has a JSON body (with the blanks filled in):

```
{
  "query": "requests \n| summarize avgRequestDuration=avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 1h)",
  "applications": [
    "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/components/<applicationName>"
  ],
  "timespan": "P1D"
}
```

Edit: I've tried this query using different forms of the resource identifiers as mentioned in the documentation, including the recommended "/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/applications/" and "/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/components/".

Comment: Can you please the exact query you are trying?

Comment: @MohitVerma Yes, I have deleted my last comment and edited the question to include the body of the request.

Comment: Please share which platform you are using to hit the query with exact URL. I am assuming that you are passing the AAD auth token in the 'Authorization' header with right permission set to access all your application insight.

Comment: Also to your application try to assign Application Insights Component contributor role and see if it work.

Comment: The URL is `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appInsightsComponent>/query?api-version=2018-04-20`. Yes, I have permission to access all of the application insights objects. When I query a single application it works fine, it only fails with a permission error when I add a second application to the same query.

Comment: @MohitVerma Forgot to mention, I've tried adding those APIs and not had any success.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a couple of things I've discovered, I believe it is *impossible* to do a cross-resource query in the Azure API URL format.

1. All experimentation with adding different roles to users and experimenting with permissions failed to find anything that worked.
2. The Go SDK uses the Azure API URL format and does not allow cross-resource queries, the .NET SDK uses the Public API URL format and does allow cross-resource queries, indicating that the feature set is different for the two APIs.

I would be happy to be proven wrong or to have this proven correct with a better reference.